# How to detect the region of a block programatically

Tags: 7, blocks, theming

I need to create a custom submit handler when blocks that are assigned to a certain region are saved (whether an existing or a new block)

I am using :

```
function MY_MODULE_NAME_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form['#id'] == 'block-admin-configure'){

    //If the block being saved is in region "Header" then do something
  }
```

Can someone tell me what to replace my commented line with please ?

Comment: What if the theme it's being saved in doesn't have a "header"region?

Comment: This functionality is just for a custom module for a specific client & theme.

Comment: Attach a submit handler, in that handler loop over `array_filter($form_state['regions'])`, that contains the selected regions by machine name

Comment: Thanks Clive, but can you give me an example?... when I view the properties for $form_state, regions isn't there.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement [hook_block_save($delta = '', $edit = array())](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_save/7.x) to execute your custom code.